# .net and visual foxpro interoperability

Tags: c#, .net, visual-foxpro

I do not have much knowledge about the interoperability between .net and visual foxpro. Is it possible to access all controls, forms etc using com and modify and add features in .net and vice- versa. How does the interoperability works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the things can be done using foxpro.

I'm currently migrating a large VFP application.

There the VFP Application hosts an .net com assembly.
You can also put .net Controls in a active X and put dem on the VFP Applications.
But there may be issues concering refreshes and display bugs depending on how your application is implemented.

The FoxPro database can be accessed via oledb. But it is not thread safe and hase some issues getting correct data.

All of these topics are to big to explain them in a single post. but Rickstrahl has some very good tutorials on his website.

One example [here](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2005/Dec/24/Advanced-FoxPro-NET-COM-Interop-Article-Series)

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: when you talk about migrating vfp application is it reusing class and objects using com. Can it be like integrating complete vfp application to .net and adding feature like forms etc in .net and . Am i correct with the concept of migrating and interoperability

Comment: WEll we tend to rewrite the code, which results in a much better result. For this we create .net com components and are using it in the vfp environment

Comment: For Calling VFP Com Components from .net see -> http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/VfpDotNetInterop/aspcominterop.asp

Comment: And vice versa -> http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/VfpDotNetInterop/DotNetFromVFP.asp

Comment: Are the .net com components you are using in vfp limited to classes and database objects or complete forms, buttons etc created in .net

Comment: With this activex host I mentioned i can use .net on foxpro.
But I never used the opposite, also I'm not sure wether this would be a good idea

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at these resources.

1. [Chapter 15 from .Net for Visual FoxPro Developers](http://foxcentral.net/microsoft/NETforVFPDevelopers_Chapter15.htm).
   This gives you step by step instructions on creating a Com Sever in Visual FoxPro
   and how to access it with .Net.
2. [.NET Interop for Visual FoxPro Applications](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/VfpDotNetInterop/vfpDotNetInterop.htm)